# Are there problems that are DSPACE(O(1)) complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata, p-vs-np

I know there are problems that are NL-complete, NP-Complete, PSPACE-complete, etc. Are there problems that are DSPACE(O(1))-complete I.e. NSPACE(O(1))-Complete I.e. Reg-Complete?

Thanks!

Comment: Complete with respect to what kind of reduction?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus, this is a great point I hadn't thought of. I'm not well versed with L vs. NL but are NL-complete problems complete with respect to a polynomial reduction? Or Logarithmic? If this too is polynomial then Reg-Complete with respect to polynomial reduction.

Comment: Every non-trivial regular language (i.e., one different from $\emptyset,\Sigma^*$ is regular-complete with respect to polynomial reductions. To make the notion of completeness non-trivial, you have to choose a type of reduction which is weaker than your class. For example, NL-completeness is defined using logspace reductions, and L-completeness using first-order reductions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES**, there are.

At the beginning of "[Andreas Krebs, Klaus-Jörn Lange: Dense Completeness. Developments in Language Theory 2012: 178-189](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=Mz26BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=completeness%20regular%20languages&source=bl&ots=U6pl_U3u-q&sig=0g0sopIAgCrQBJMfY0d4_Dg7-vo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7yL_5-uvdAhVHSX0KHbxiCw04ChDoATAFegQIAhAB#v=onepage&q=completeness%20regular%20languages&f=false)"[Section 6], it is stated that some REG languages with a non-solvable monoid are complete for $\mathrm{NC}^1$ under $\mathrm{DLOGTIME}$-uniform $\mathrm{AC}^0$ reductions. The section goes on to state that a REG language is either in $\mathrm{AC}^0$ or its syntactic monoids are non-aperiodic.

[Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:R#reg) states that REG is contained in $\mathrm{NC}^1$.

So, some REG language is complete for the class itself. This is **non-trivial**.